# How can I use web.whatsapp.com on an Android phone with a broken screen?

Tags: screen, qr-code, whatsapp-messenger

My Android phone's screen died: no image, no touch, nada. How can I use http://web.whatsapp.com/ without being able to start WhatsApp and browse to the option Menu > Whatsapp Web so I can scan the QR Code on the web page?

This is obviously an interim solution until my new phone arrives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly start WhatsApp with the correct activity intent via [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html):

```
adb shell "su -c 'am start com.whatsapp/.qrcode.QrCodeActivity'"
```

Then hold your camera in front of the QR Code @ http://web.whatsapp.com/.

Requirements:

- a rooted Android phone (outside scope of this post)
- working `adb` (like [Minimal ADB + Fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) or [ADB for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb-for-chrome/njhehnieenekbompacofnhlljnobgcga))
- working SuperUser `su` binary

Found it with something along the lines of:

```
adb shell "su -c 'find /data -name *whatsapp*.dex | xargs strings | grep Qr'"
```

Comment: Are you sure you need root for this? `am start` doesn't normally need root, maybe unless this activity is not `exported` in the manifest.

Comment: It might not be needed, but as far as I could see, the `shell` user does not have the rights to start the `com.whatsapp/.qrcode.QrCodeActivity` intent.